# Might my Muslim classmates be offended by nude art in a presentation?

Tags: art

I am giving a presentation in a language class, and have chosen the topic of French artist Henri Matisse. As part of the presentation I will be showing images of his paintings and drawings. Some of my classmates are muslim and I know that Islam has some rules about exposure to nudity, but I don't understand them well.

Might my Muslim classmates be offended or upset by seeing Matisse's nude art in a presentation?

Examples:
Carmelina (1903)

> [image: Matisse, Carmelina (1903)]

Blue Nude (1952)

> [image: Matisse, Blue Nude (1952)]

Nude with oranges (1951)

> [image: Matisse, Nude with oranges (1951)]

Comment: They might or might not. Maybe talk to them about it so that if someone is concerned they can avoid looking.

Comment: @UmH Thanks that's good advice. Do you think the more abstract images e.g. Blue Nude would be more acceptable? Or is it the concept of nudity that is problematic, not the representation.

Comment: I think that abstract images such as the last two could be more acceptable, however it again depends on personal temperament. The problem is looking at actual naked body of a real person, however even abstract nude art may be objected to if it raises obscene thoughts or spreads immorality.

Comment: If I were in this class, I'd find them unacceptable. I'd probably leave the classroom as soon as I see Carmelina or Nude with oranges. I wouldn't worry about the abstract Blue if it was shown for only a few seconds.